# Imaging Process for Multiple Hardware configurations

Tags: windows-7, drivers, pxe-boot, dfs, imaging

currently we use a PXE environment to deploy an automated imaging process to PC's for windows 7.  We are using an unattended installation with an answer file.  This answer file tells the windows installation to look to out DFS\win7x64\drivers folder to find drivers for the systems we have on our network and it works fine.  However we are adding new PC's to our company newer models with different hardware specs, when I add the drivers for these new PC's to the driver store they image fine, however the older PC's blue screen during the windows imaging process.  When I remove the new drivers from the DFS point, the old ones image once again, the new ones image as well but without drivers.  So my question is how do I get this to function correctly?

Comment: I should mention it seems to be the USB 3.0 and Chipset drivers specifically

Comment: try a script to detect hardware via wmi, if machine is an older model, script does nothing, if newer model detected, it sends a `DISM /Add-Driver -recurse` command.